# Does Surah Luqman refer to write novels and short stories?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

AssalamuAilakum,

In the opening verses of Surah Luqman when it refers to idle talks, some say it refers to singing, is it also stories etc. Too?

I am asking because as an English Major I intended to write a fantasy genre story but about good morals and religious allegory. I know there are other muslim writers like this too.

Jzk

Answer (score -2):

It has been referred to as songs, movies, books, games, any form of Haram entertainment.

Comment: Would it be haram if the intention of the writing of the book was to display large moral themes and be an allegory for things like the temporal nature of the world? This kind of thing has also been done by other writers from other religions, because through literature such ideas can be conveyed through a more accessible way?

Comment: I’m not sure as to what you are asking now, but if the book has been written for education, history, or anything Islamic, it is not wasting time. However, if you read books containing Haram themes such as romance, it will be considered as Haram entertainment.